# Clear setInterval when user clicks on an autoscroll script

Tags: jquery, slider, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm working on an autoscroll script, I'm using a function in jquery to move to the clicked element on the menu. And I'm using a setInterval to click every item on the menu. Til now everything works ok. But the problem comes when I need to stop the setInterval, I mean, stop the setInterval if a user click one of the elements.

I have two issues or questions for *yous*:

1. Is this the correct way to do an autoscroll?
2. If is not, I'd really appreciate if you give me a little clue to do it. If it is the correct way, how to know if the click event was triggered by the user or by the script?

Well. Thanks for reading. The code I'm using is the next and, as I said, is working ok to loop trought the slider. THANKS A LOT. Just as a sidenote: for a client petition, I cannot use a jquery plugin to create the slider, so I have to do it manually.

```
$('.slider-controls a').live('click',function(e){
            moveSlider($(this).attr('href'),e);

            return false;
        });

        function moveSlider(toDiv,elem){
            var nextPos = $(toDiv).position().top;
            $('.slider-total').animate({
                top: -nextPos
            }, 700);

            $('.slider-total div').removeClass('activo');
            $(toDiv).addClass('activo');
        }

        var autoSlider = setInterval(function(){
            var slideNext;

            if ( !($('.slider-total .activo').next().attr('id')) ){
                slideNext = '#' + $('.slider-total .post:first').attr('id');
            } else {
                slideNext = '#' + $('.slider-total .activo').next().attr('id');
            }

            $('a[href='+slideNext+']').click();
        },4000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clear interval by calling `clearInterval()` passing the id of the interval, returned from `setInterval()` function. In your case it will be:

```
clearInterval(autoSlider);
```

Comment: Yes. I know that it actually stops my setInterval. What I need is to stop the setInterval when a user clicks an item. I could use clearInterval(autoSlider) in the $('.slider-controls a').live('click'); function. The problem here is that the scripts itself is clicking every item, so if I use it that way, the slider only animates to the second item.

Comment: Inside your `setInterval` function call `moveSlider` directly. Then you can clear timeout in `click` event, as it will come from the user. Always try to extract your logic to separate methods you can call from events or your javascript, without 'pretending' to be the user